# Bootstrap 5 Navbar stays collapsed

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I copied everything from Bootstrap, but my navbar stays collapsed on mobile and tablet. When i click the icon, there is a movement, like they try to go up and down.
I attached the code below :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav my-5 fs-5">
                    <li class="nav-item me-5">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-5">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tour List</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-5">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tour Search</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- LOGO -->

                    <img src="/images/Landing-logo.png" width="125px" alt="">

                    <!-- LOGO -->
                    <li class="nav-item ms-5">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Desinations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ms-5">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ms-5">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is  code snippet for responsive navbar  you can adjust it accordingly.

````
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>```
````

Comment: thank you, is it working now, but i don't know why it doesn't center using d-flex and justify-content-center in the same div

Comment: I think in ul tag  you have to add mx-auto to get in center nav items